# ¿Por qué mis sonidos personalizados no funcionan en mis notificaciones expo?

Tags: android, nodejs, react-native, push-notification, expo

Estoy intentando personalizar el tono de mis notificaciones mediante la API de Expo pero suenan las notificaciones que tengo por defecto en mi teléfono, según vi en Expo, hay que modificarlo en el archivo app.json de la siguiente manera:

```
{
...
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-notifications",
    {
      "icon": "./assets/notification-icon.png",
      "color": "#E32726",
      "androidMode": "default",
      "sounds":[
        "./assets/notify.wav"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
...
}
```

Y también agregar los permisos:

```
{
...
"android": {
  ...
  "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
  "permissions": ["RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"]
}
...
}
```

Luego se configura el canal de las notificaciones en mi applicación de react native:

```
Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('notificacion', {
  name: 'Notificaciones',
  importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
  sound: 'notify.wav'
}).then(result => {
  console.log("Todo bien");
  console.log(result);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log("Error");
  console.log(error);
});
```

Esta sería la configuración, pero cuando lo pruebo con la API de Expo, genera la notificación pero se escucha con el tono que tengo en mi dispositivo. No se que es lo que esta sucediendo en si, pero ¿Qué puedo hacer para que se pueda escuchar un tono personalizado? o ¿todos usan el mismo tono?

Estoy usando Expo: 48.0.18